# Iterative Functional Equation on $ \mathbb N $: $ f \Big( f \big( f ( n ) \big) \Big) + 6 f ( n ) = 3 f \big( f ( n ) \big) + 4 n + 2001 $

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $ f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $ satisfying
> $$ f \Big( f \big( f ( n ) \big) \Big) + 6 f ( n ) = 3 f \big( f ( n ) \big) + 4 n + 2001 , \forall n \in \mathbb N \text . $$

After some trial and error, I assumed the solution to be of the form $ f ( n ) = n + r $, which gave me $ f ( n ) = n + 667 $ as a solution, but I am unable to come up with any other solutions. How would you guys solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
$$ g_n(d) = f^{(d)}(n) - 667d. $$
Routine computation yields the recurrence equation
$$ g_n(d+3) = 3g_n(d+2) - 6g_n(d+1) + 4g_n(d). $$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$ x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 4 = (x-1)(x^2-2x+4). $$
The two roots of $x^2-2x+4$ are $2e^{\pm i \pi/3}$.

It follows from the general theory of recurrence relations that for some real $A,B$ and angle $\theta$,
$$g_n(d) = A + B2^d \cos (d\pi/3 + \theta).$$
The cosine part is a periodic function in $d$ attaining $6$ fixed values, at least one of them strictly positive and at least one strictly negative. In particular, if $B \neq 0$ then for some $e \in \{0,\ldots,5\}$ we have
$$C \triangleq B\cos (e\pi/3 + \theta) < 0.$$
This implies that
$$f^{(6d+e)}(n) = g_n(6d+e) + 4002d + 667e = A + 2^d C + 4002d + 667e $$
is eventually negative. This contradicts the premise that $f \geq 0$, and so $B = 0$. Substituting $d = 0$ in the formula for $g_n$, we deduce that $g_n(d) = A = n$ and so
$$ f^{(d)}(n) = n + 667d. $$
In particular, $f(n) = n + 667$.

Comment: Nice. How did you know to make that choice for $g_n(d)$? Where did the $667d$ come from?

Comment: Hindsight is always 20-20.  Knowing that $f^{(d)}(n) = n + 667d$ is a solution, you notice that subtracting $667 d$ gives you something simpler.

Comment: Conversely, $667d$ is the term you need to subtract in order to get a homogeneous recurrence relation. Alternatively, instead of subtracting it we get a non-homogeneous recurrence relation. To solve it, we need to solve the corresponding homogeneous relation, and add some fixed solution to the non-homogeneous recurrence. We already know that $667d$ is such a solution, and we continue as before. I thought that presenting it the way I did is cleaner, although the derivation was along the lines just described.

Comment: As for choosing to look at iterates of $f$, this is suggested by the form of the functional equation. Moreover, lately I have been working on something that involves solving a non-homogeneous recurrence relation (though with non-constant coefficients), so this "solution pattern" suggested itself after a short while.